# Biconomy gasless transactions library with Web3.js throwing API error

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, frontend

I have a front end made with react meant to interact with my smart contract deployment. I'm using the Biconomy protocol so that I can enable gasless transactions for people that will use my app.

However, when calling the functions from my front end I get the following error:[image]

This is my front end **`app.js`**:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './App.css';
import Web3 from 'web3-eth'
import Biconomy from "@biconomy/mexa";

import 'react-notifications/lib/notifications.css';
const { config } = require("./config");

let web3;
let biconomy;
let contract;


function App() {

    //My state variables added here below
    const [farmAgent, setAgentForWhitelistingFarm] = useState();

    //My state variables above


    const [owner, setOwner] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {

        biconomy = new Biconomy(window.ethereum, { apiKey: "EEx4HcTA2.1edb119a-55c0-45e7-9e75-e1bb4204ffb3", strictMode: false, debug: true });

        web3 = new Web3(biconomy);

        biconomy.onEvent(biconomy.READY, async () => {
            // Initialize your dapp here like getting user accounts etc
            console.log("biconomy Ready");

            await window.ethereum.enable();
            contract = new web3.Contract(config.contract.abi, config.contract.address);
        }).onEvent(biconomy.ERROR, (error, message) => {
            // Handle error while initializing mexa
            console.log(error)
        });
    }
        , []);

    window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', (accounts) => {
        setOwner(accounts);
    });


    async function handleSubmit4WhitelistingFarmAgent(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(contract);
        console.log(contract.methods);
        console.log(web3.currentProvider);

        await contract.methods.whiteListHostingProvidor(farmAgent).send({ from: owner[0] });

    }


    return (
        <div className="App">

            <div>

                <p>Account: {owner}</p>


                <section>

                    <h2>krtr Admin</h2>

                    <h5>Whitelist Farm Agent</h5>
                    <form onSubmit={e => { handleSubmit4WhitelistingFarmAgent(e) }}>

                        <input type="text" name="agentForOnboardingFarm" onChange={e => setAgentForWhitelistingFarm(e.target.value)} />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit Agent Address" />

                    </form>

                </section>

            </div>
        </div >
    );
}

export default App;
```

In the file above, `async function handleSubmit4WhitelistingFarmAgent(e)` is what I'm calling from the front end which is causing an error.

As you can see when I instantiate biconomy in the `useEffect()` function in the beginning of `app.js`, that strict mode is set to `false`. Before it would work when it was set to `false`, but not when it was set to `true`. But now, it *won't* work either way even though I haven't really changed the code at all...

I am using the SDK method of the Standard EIP 2771 Approach from the [Biconomy docs](https://docs.biconomy.io/products/enable-gasless-transactions/eip-2771/code-changes/sdk)

I'm sure I registered the dApp and the contract/contract methods correctly in the Biconomy dashboard.

**I have reached out to the official several devs of Biconomy on their telegram, and although they've replied, it's been days and they've been of no use at all...**

What I've tried:

Deploying on: Rinkeby, Kovan, Matic Mainnet

Confirmed the state is being read correctly when calling the contract function `whiteListHostingProvidor()`. Specifically the state of `farmAgent` which is the parameter of that function.

I've confirmed that the contract instance exists before I call the function mentioned just above on the contract.

The code for my smart contract, which my biconomy instance calls goes like this:

```
contract KraterMasterNoNFT is  ERC2771Context {

constructor(

        address _forwarder

    )  ERC2771Context(

       _forwarder
    ) {}

// contract logic

}
```

*I also changed all `msg.sender`(s) to `_msgSender()` in my contract, as instructed by the Biconomy docs*

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have window.ethereum defined while initializing biconomy. You can put window.ethereum in the dependency array and try again. Although I'd advise you to use the newer SDK since it's way better than old one.